# Pojo class name Serialization

Tags: java, jackson, retrofit2

**I WANT TO SERIALIZE WITH CUSTOM NAME DONT CLASS NAME**

I alreay know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453703/include-class-name-in-all-objects-serialized-by-jackson). Pls dont refer to this answer.

How to Serialize pojo class name with jackson.
Example:

```
public class A{
private int a;
//getter seeter
}
```

when serialize A want to be like:

```
{"a": 1,"class":"ARequest"}
```

how to serialize Pojo with given `className`. Is it possible without override `toString()` method .I used this class in retrofit Post method body.

One point i dont serialize it under class name like:

```
{"ARequest":{"a":5}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your class with [`@JsonTypeInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="class")
public class Foo {

    public String bar;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Then consider the following code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(foo));
```

It will produce the following output:

```
{
  "class" : "Foo",
  "bar" : "test"
}
```

If you want the full qualified name of the class, such as `org.example.Foo`, you can use [`JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#CLASS) instead of [`JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#NAME).

Comment: how to set serialization className?

Comment: @sajib Jackson will handle that for you.

Comment: is it possible give custom class name like jsonproperty

Comment: @sajib That's a whole different question though.

Comment: i said serialize with given ClassName. sry for not clearify properly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="class")` as described [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization#12-per-class-annotations)