# Add type information when serializing class with Jackson so that it's possible to deserialize using interface type without using annotations?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

This question is similar to [include class name in all objects serialized by jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453703/include-class-name-in-all-objects-serialized-by-jackson) but I want to configure this by default *without* using annotations on each class. Preferably I'd like to add a `field` to the serialized json, such as `_class` or `_type` that contains the class name of the serialized class (preferably not event fully qualified, but I'm ok with that). I'm using Jackson 2.11.1.

For example let's say I have this interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {}
```

and two implementations:

```
public class MyClass1 implements MyInterface {

    private String something;

    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {
    
    private String somethingElse;

    public String getSomethingElse() {
        return somethingElse;
    }

    public void setSomethingElse(String somethingElse) {
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to serialize instances of `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` so that I can deserialize them as `MyInterface` (i.e. adding type information when serializing).

I've read in the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization#11-global-default-typing) that you should be able to configure the `ObjectMapper` like this to make it work:

```
PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder().build();
objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv); // default to using DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE
```

But when I try this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder().build();
objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv); // default to using DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE

MyClass1 myClass1 = new MyClass1();
myClass1.setSomething("something");

String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myClass1);

MyInterface myInterface = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyInterface.class);
```

I get this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class org.something.MyInterface
 at [Source: (String)"{"something":"something"}"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

If I change the configuration to use `ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING` then Jackson actually seem to wrap the type in an array but I still get an exception when trying to deserialize:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder().build();
objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING);

MyClass1 myClass1 = new MyClass1();
myClass1.setSomething("something");

String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myClass1);

MyInterface myInterface = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyInterface.class);
```

the exception now is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'org.something.MyClass1' as a subtype of `org.something.MyInterface`: Configured `PolymorphicTypeValidator` (of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator`) denied resolution
 at [Source: (String)"["org.something.MyClass1",{"something":"something"}]"; line: 1, column: 53]
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually got it working by configuring the `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(new LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator(), ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING);
```

Not sure if this is the idiomatic way to do it though.

Comment: I have no idea what this does or the implications but it is awesome!

Comment: It's in the docs why: 'Does not do any validation, allows all subtypes.'

Answer (score 0):

While building PolymorphicTypeValidator, if you provide the package where your sub classes reside, it should work fine. You need to do like this:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
                .allowIfSubType("com.example.core")
                .build();
  mapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING);
```

> com.example.core

is the package where all of the subclasses reside.